# Dual national with passports in with different names (maiden and married)

Tags: passports, bookings, dual-nationality

I'm curious which surname to use when booking a flight roundtrip to Brazil.
My Brazilian passport has my maiden name, and my American passport has my married name. Which surname should I use when booking my flight?

Comment: Use your married name, and carry both passports and your marriage certificate. Then see the linked question.

Comment: I basically agree with @CannonFodder, but if there's some reason to use your maiden name, you could use that instead.  When flying to the US, you can show the Brazilian passport to prove your identity as the person named on the ticket, and the US passport to prove your admissibility to the US.  There no reason to avoid showing both.